# create Nodejs/Express API to connect to React-Admin frontend Framework

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-admin

[react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/)
Is a frontend Framework for building admin applications running in the browser on top of REST/GraphQL APIs, using ES6, React and Material Design. Previously named admin-on-rest. Open sourced and maintained by marmelab.

I'm trying to create and configure a Rest API (backend) using Nodejs/Express, I want to know how to configure the requests and the endpoints in my express API.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = 80;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('Received a GET HTTP method');
});
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('Received a POST HTTP method');
});
app.put('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('Received a PUT HTTP method');
});
app.delete('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('Received a DELETE HTTP method');
});
app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`),
);
```

Comment: Can you add more info about what would you like to do, what is your database and so on? Or problem is just a create router for your application? Maybe you can specify what kind of resources you are what to access with API...

Comment: my Database is Postgresql and my Server is NodeJs/express and I want to create a full stuck web application with the frontend [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS [PROJECT](https://github.com/michalak111/react-admin-panel) PERFECTLY ANSWERS MY QUESTION (except that it use mongodb).
Thank you [Michalak111](https://github.com/michalak111)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on which [react-admin data provider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html) you are using. Data providers work as an adapter between react-admin and the specific API you use. There is no "standard" API specification for react-admin.

There is an example [ra-data-simple-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest) which might suit your needs if you really want to write your own API from scratch in Express.

The better solution might be to use something like [Feathers](https://feathersjs.com/) and [feathers-postgresql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/feathers-postgresql) for your API, and then use the existing data provider [ra-data-feathers](https://github.com/josx/ra-data-feathers) to connect react-admin to Feathers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Nick Nelson, I thought that I have to create a [Rest Cient](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html) not a [Data Provider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html) what's the difference between them ?

Comment: The https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html link is for admin-on-rest. admin-on-rest was renamed to react-admin at version 2.

Rest Client and Data Provider are basically the same thing in this context. The only difference is that Rest Client is for admin-on-rest and Data Provider is for react-admin.

I'd suggest staying away from the admin-on-rest documentation when working with react-admin. There are significant changes between the two, and mixing the documentation is likely to get confusing.

Comment: Hello @nick, I'm still confused in the way to make this project work correctly, Actually I want to create from scratch a NodeJs/Express server with database Postgres but it seems that I have to create a DataProvider ... and I have no idea how to do that ... is there any examples of full stack project with react-admin that can help me ... because I can't found such a project !!

Comment: You don't **have** to create a DataProvider. You could write an API that conforms to the standards expected by an existing DataProvider like [ra-data-json-server](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-json-server) or [ra-data-simple-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest).

Comment: I'd suggest you start with the [react-admin tutorial](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html) which will show you how to set up a simple react-admin project using the ra-data-simple-rest data provider and an existing API, and then look at a tutorial on writing an API with Express like [this](https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js-d7e59c7a3dfb). Doing both of those should give you everything you need to then combine the two, so your react-admin app connects to your Express API.